# Multiple variables have the same address, yet they don't?

Tags: c

I was just goofing around on C, as I had just learned more about pointers. But my main confusing point was about addresses, I was just checking out random variable addresses and here's what I found.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=5;
    int y=4;
    int z=8;



    printf("%p\n",&x);
    printf("%p\n",&y);
    printf("%p\n",&z);


}
```

This code shows 3 different addresses, which is what to be expected. If I only have one printf statement, like this

```
printf("%p\n",&x);
```

It will show me one of the addresses, which is expected as well. But, if I remove the variable 'x', and use another variable like 'y', or 'z', it will show me the exact same address that 'x' had. How is that possible?

So basically, when you check all the variables' addresses in the same code, each will have a different address. If you check each of them separately, they will have the exact same address.

PS: This only happens for integers and floats, I tried the same with char and each variable gave a separate address.

Comment: compiler eliminates unused variables

Comment: The answers do not seem to be answering the question, which I understand to mean you have removed `x` from the code altogether, and `y` now has the address that `x` had before. *" if I remove the variable `x`..."* Imagine a sloping shelf with 3 cups on it. When you remove the lowest cup, the others slide down to occupy the previously used space.

Comment: Add a couple of lines of code that make sure that all three variables are used `x += y;` `x += z;`  Then try the single variable address prints and see the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is optimizing away unused variables in your code. This is [dead code elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination).

So when you have code like this

```
int main()
{
    int x=5;
    int y=4;
    int z=8;

    printf("%p\n",&z);
}
```

The compiler can tell that you never use x or y, and therefore can remove that code from the compiled object. This makes your generated code faster and generates smaller object sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, the compiler is eliminating the unused variables. Hence, only the ones you are calling to print are getting created.

Answer (score 1):

"*But, if I remove the variable 'x', and use another variable like 'y', or 'z', it will show me the exact same address that 'x' had.*"

This has nothing to do with optimizing away as other answers suggest, though the result is the same: in your second test you did not declare your variable. Your program then looks like

```
int main()
{
    //int x=5;  // commented out
    int y=4;
    int z=8;

    //printf("%p\n",&x);  // commented out
    printf("%p\n",&y);
    printf("%p\n",&z);
}
```

For each variable, the compiler reserves space (here: on the stack) and this compiler apparently does that in the order it encounters your declarations (nearly all compilers do that). `x` no longer being declared, all following variables just move up in the address space.

Note that it does that for all variables, also `char` variables. But for `char` variables you often give a size. Consider:

```
char s1[10];
char s2[10];
char s3[10];
```

and:

```
//char s1[10];  // commented out
char s2[10];
char s3[10];
```

`s2` of the second example will have the same adress as `s1` in rhe first example because all these `s` variables are the same size. Were they different sizes you would see different addresses but yoy can calculate these differences from their sizes. (Note: "padding" can come into play here, where the compiler allocates slightly more then you declare so the next variable starts on a 4 byte/8 byte boundary (4: 32 bit compilation; 8: 64 bit compilation).